# Line-Neutral-Ground instrument to be plugged to a Line to Line power source

Tags: ac

What are the problems that may occur when a Line-Neutral-Ground instrument is plugged to a Line to Line power source?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it safe to plug the L-N-Gnd to a Line to Line source?

Comment: Where did you manage to find a Line to Line power source?

Comment: further details required.  Where are you?  In North America, L-N implies 120 volts, while L-L would be 240 volts.  Plugging a 120 volt device into 240 volts is unwise :-)  If both sources are the same voltage, there should be no problem.

Comment: L-L would be 208V not 240V (for star connection)

Comment: But if it's a 230V European product, and it's plugged into a 220V 2-phase US power supply, it may well work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is wrong voltage. Line to line voltages are usually higher than line to neutral voltages.

Some old or unusual equipment may have problems if it's "neutral" connection is not close to earth potential but such equipment is by far the exception not the rule. Remember large parts of the world use unpolarised sockets so any manufacturer whose appliance couldn't tolerate it's "neutral" pin being away from earth potential would be severely limiting their market.

Fuses and circuit breakers in the appliance may be rendered less effective in such a situation but if there is a RCD/GFCI present then it should mitigate that risk.

Overall if it's a modern portable appliance and the voltage is correct it will almost certainly be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Typical problems may include, but are not limited to:

- physically incompatible connectors
- smoke
- melting plastic
- fire
- electric shock
- blown fuses / breakers

Comment: If the voltage is (near enough) correct, only the first of those may be an issue, and plugs are easy enough to change.

Comment: @SimonB In the US, and I bet other 120V countries, L-L voltage is 240V. That's probably not "near enough" correct for most things. Plus, the safety certification of devices with a polarized plug is based on the assumption that the neutral connection is (absent some fault) at ground potential and not a shock hazard. If you connect that to live instead, even if you do get the voltages "near enough", the device may no longer meet safety standards. It's a bad idea, generally.